# Scapy ARP function not giving proper output when running it

Tags: python, python-3.x, networking, scapy, arp

I have a simple script:

```
import scapy.all as scapy

def scan(ip):
    arg = scapy.ARP(pdst=ip)
    print(arg.summary())
scan("192.168.11.0/24")
```

But when I run this script the output I get is:

```
ARP who has ?? says ??
```

Normally the summary would give me 2 IP address's where the 2 question marks are but for some reason that is not the case. Also I have made a network scanner and It was working fine yesterday and returned to me all ip and mac address on the network but today I can't seem to pass in a range(ex:"192.168.11.0/24")when I do the only output I get is:

```
IP          MAC Address
----------------------------------------------------
192.168.11.1        08:02:8e:a1:6a:d0
```

Even though there are more devices in the network. Is there something wrong with scapy? If so how should I delete and reinstall it because I have already done pip uninstall scapy and pip install scapy and nothing works still.

Answer (score 0):

You're not actually doing anything with your script. Your function includes `arg = scapy.ARP(pdst=ip)`, which creates an ARP packet. To send it, use [sr or sr1](https://scapy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html#send-and-receive-packets-sr). There are also ARP example one-liners that cover [ARP pings](https://scapy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html#arp-ping). Applied here,

```py
from scapy.all import *

def arp_scan(ips):
    resp = arping(ips)
    print(resp)
arp_scan("192.168.11.0/24")
```

We will get output that looks similar to

```
Begin emission:
*Finished sending 256 packets.

Received 1 packets, got 1 answers, remaining 255 packets
  9c:5c:12:ca:7b:6f 192.168.11.1
```