# Scapy is not working when IP is used as range in the ARP packet

Tags: python, python-3.x, scapy

Python Version: **3.8.1**

Scapy Version: **2.4.3**

**Where Working?**

It is working fine with a single IP address.

[image: Case Where Worked]

**Where Not Working?**

When passing the IP range in the constructor, it never worked.

But when we assign IP range, it works sometimes.

[image: Cases Where Not Worked]

**Tried Methods?**

tried in the script, like

```
from scapy.all import ARP
arp_request = ARP()
arp_request.pdst = ip
print(arp_request.summary())
```

tried in terminal using scapy, whose screenshot attached above

I know the question is already been asked on

[Scapy ARP function not giving proper output when running it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58259896/scapy-arp-function-not-giving-proper-output-when-running-it)

But it has no answers.

**EDIT:** 
I tried to analyze packets sent by the main device using Wireshark on one of the devices present in the network.

I find that in spite of showing range as ??, sometime ARP request covers whole range 0-256 and programs stop successfully.
But sometimes it stops at 192.168.43.170 and keeps sending the request for 192.168.43.1.  And this also blocks the internet.

I don't know why at 192.168.43.170 because my gateway is at 192.168.43.1 and devices are at 192.168.43.98 and 192.168.43.198

**Wireshark Output**

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This was a bug in scapy

**Bug:**

https://github.com/secdev/scapy/issues/2400

Which fixed recently

**Fix:**

https://github.com/secdev/scapy/pull/2395

**Latest code.**

https://github.com/secdev/scapy

Comment: To be precise: the fact that ?? was displayed was indeed a bug that was fixed before this issue was even raised. Nothing was done against the "block internet" issue because it's likely a host issue.